# Word for a person who speaks in a video

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I made a video on a computer (where I clicked here and there and did stuff). I am not seen in the video; only the screen is seen.
I commented on and explained the stuff I clicked.

What is the word for a person who does this explanation?

I want to put a text into the video stating some data and also stating my name as the person who did the talking. Like this:

```
Company: ...my company...
Date: ...the date...
person-who-did-the-talking: ...my name...
```

So it has to be one word.

The translations from my mother tongue word "Sprecher" (German) range from "speaker" over "spokesperson", "talker", "narrator" to "enunciator" and "announcer". I have no idea which one to use, or if any of them even fits here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing is called a [voice-over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice-over). The terms I've personally seen used to describe the person speaking in a voice-over are:

- narrator
- commentator
- presenter

Edit:

- voice-over artist

Comment: In American English (AmE), *narrator* or possibly *commentator*. The use of *presenter* is not (widely) used in American English and will sound strange to many/most speakers of AmE; I think it's British English.

Comment: @AlanCarmack thanks for your comment. As far as I can recall, I've only ever heard people with a British or Anglo-Indian accent using *presenter* in this sense, although the data sample was too small for me to make a bold claim.

Answer (score 4):

I would use narrator, but speaker is fine.

A **narrator** is almost always unseen. The word narrator is used most often when that parson is telling a story, or  explaining what is happening on screen/in the text/etc.

A **speaker** would just be a more general term, and would not be incorrect.

The word **talker** is not commonly used, **announcer** generally refers to sports or scorekeeping, and **enunciator** is explaining/expanding on ideas (also not commonly used).